# How to include the specific header file when there are two same files in system include path?

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

I notice this question:

[Two header with same name in include path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784848/two-header-with-same-name-in-include-path)

But the problem I encounter is the include path is system include path.

Suppose two headers: dir1/header.h  dir2/header.h, they are located in system include path, and dir1 is searched firstly, but the one I really want is dir2/header.h. What could I do in this case?

It's in the Android NDK environment.

Suppose the two system include paths are:

```
dir1:$(NDK_ROOT)\sources\cxx-stl\gabi++\include

dir2:$(NDK_ROOT)\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.6\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.6\include
```

Now I want the header in dir2. But the Android compiler will search the header in dir1 firstly. If I used the -I option, How can I change the dir2 path into a platform-independent path (e.g. windows-x86_64 may be linux-x86)?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `#include "dir2/header.h"` in your source file, then on the compile line you list the parent directory with `-I`; so for example if the fully-qualified pathname of the second header was `/usr/local/include/dir2/header.h` you would add `-I/usr/local/include` to your compile line.

*ETA*

Nate that in makefiles you should always use forward slashes, not backslashes.

Also, the compiler *always* searches the directories you provide on the command line with `-I`, in the order you specify them, *before* it searches any of the standard locations.  So I don't really understand the problem.  If the default location is the one you *don't* want anyway, then just add a `-I` flag pointing to the other one and it'll be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. There are two header files '*cuda.h'*, one in the system path *'/usr/local/cuda/include/cuda.h'*, anoter one is specified with *'-I'* in Makefile, i.e. -I

```
${PWD}/dependency/libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/cuda.h.
```

I want to include the first one, but the second one was referred. Then I tried to replace `'#include <cuda.h>'` with `'#include "../../../local/cuda/include/cuda.h"'`. It works.

Hope this could help you.